# SQL: user defined columns

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, entity-attribute-value

In my application I need a member list with custom columns. So I create a members table with only the ID. The member_attributes table contains the name and the type (e.g. 'Name', 'string' or 'Birthday', 'date'). In the third table I have the foreign key of members table (member_id), the foreign key for the attribute table (member_attribute_id) and the value of the attribute.

> **members**: id, timestamps
>
> **member_attributes**: id, name, type, timestamps
>
> **member_attribute_values**: member_id, member_attribute_id, value

First question: is this the correct method to achieve this. It's working so far.

And second question is how to select all attributes, even if they are empty. I tried a right join, but that does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM member_attributes
RIGHT JOIN member_attribute_values on (member_attribute_values.member_attribute_id = member_attributes.id)
RIGHT JOIN members on (members.id = member_attribute_values.member_id)
```

Check this fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e097b/1

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table left join optional data` easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Whether you use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` doesn't matter, so long as you understand what they mean. However, since it is normal to read from left to right (in English in any case), you may find `LEFT JOIN` easier to use (as per comment by @jarlh).

Comment: Adding to what jarlh and Peter say -- since there are 3 tables, is it `(a RIGHT b) RIGHT c` or is it `a RIGHT (b RIGHT c)` -- the choice here could influence the outcome.  (I don't happen to know which way it is parsed.)

Comment: _Often_ people say `LEFT JOIN`, when they really mean `JOIN`.  Perhaps `RIGHT` is not necessary here?

Comment: EAV schema is fraught with issues.  Follow the tag I added.  For performance in a key-value table, see my tips [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `Cross join` and `Sub-Query`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT members.id as member_id, attributes.id as attributesid, name, type FROM attributes, members) as t
left join member_attribute_values as mav on t.member_id = mav.member_id and
t.attributesid = mav.member_attribute_id
order by t.member_id
```

SQL Fiddler: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3799f/9

Comment: This is not working. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e097b/1
For 'John Doe' (member id: 1) the 'Birthday' field should be null, but it's missing. U know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this..

I have been doing something similar in a couple of projects. I chose to use one table for both attribute name and value with a foreign key to the member.

> **member_attributes**: id, memberId, name, type, value
>
> foreign key on memberId = members(id)
>
> **members**: id

Then you can simply select all member_attributes rows for the user by a simple

```
select * from member_attributes where memberId = ?
```